# Dictionary where keys are pair of integers in Python

Tags: python, string, performance, dictionary, tuples

How is possible in Python to create a dictionary where the keys are pairs of integers?

For example, if I do this:

```
mydict=dict()
mydict[ [1,2] ] = 'xxx'
```

I get the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

So I came up with two different solutions: strings or tuples as keys.

A first solution seems to convert the pair of integers in their string representation:

```
mydict=dict()
mydict[ str(1)+" "+str(2) ] = 'xxx'
```

while the second solution involves tuples:

```
mydict=dict()
mydict[ tuple([1,2]) ] = 'xxx'
```

From some experiments I've found that the tuple solution is slower than the string one.
Is there a more efficient and fast way to use simply two integers as keys?

Comment: Tip: Read [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008). It helps a lot in making your code more readable.

Comment: I think your timings are bad. I've timed it and found that directly constructing a tuple (`mydict[(x,y)]`) is the fastest. If you construct a list first and then convert it to a tuple (which is unnecessary), it takes about 1.7 times as long (`mydict[tuple([x,y])]`). The string method is the slowest, 2.6 times slower. You can make it even faster if the tuple already exists, `mydict[some_tuple]` is 0.7 times faster than `mydict[(x,y)]`.

Comment: @lazyr Is that only for insertion or also for access?

Comment: @Hans Only insertion. I created a prepopulated list of 100'000 two-tuples with random integers and an empty `dict`, and then timed a for-loop iterating over these tuples (`for x, y in ...`) that inserted into the dict using the variuos methods. I used `None` as the inserted value for all the keys.

Comment: It would be better if used both for insertion and access.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should probably use a tuple, which can be hashed:

```
mydict = {}
mydict[(1, 2)] = 'xxx'
# or more concisely (@JamesHenstridge):
mydict[1,2] = 'xxx'
```

If that is actually too slow (don't optimise unnecessarily), then given a maximum value for the one integer, construct an index:

```
def index(a, b, maxB):
    return a*maxB + b

mydict[index(1, 2, max)] = 'xxx'
```

But be aware that a function call could easily slow it down further, so you can inline the function at the cost of readability and making it easier to introduce bugs if copy-pasted elsewhere:

```
mydict[1*max + 2] = 'xxx'
```

Incidentally, there is an SO question on *read* speeds of dictionaries with tuple keys:

[Python tuples as keys slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350002/python-tuples-as-keys-slow?rq=1)

Doing a tiny bit of profiling showed the inline index to be marginally (<5%) faster than the tuple, and both about twice as fast as the index. If this was done in PyPy, I would expect the index version (inline or not) to be faster.

On a subsidiary note; if you are worrying about the insertion speed into a dict, you may be using the wrong data structure, or perhaps doing more work than necessary. As an example, parsing a CSV file into fields in each line and storing the values in a dict this way `data[line,field]` may be unnecessary if you can make the line parsing lazy and only parse the lines that you actually pull data out of. I.e. don't do `data = parseAll(somecsv); print data[7,'date']` when you can do `dataLines = somecsv.readlines(); print getField(dataLines[7], 'date')`.

Comment: @tim-pietzcker: Cheers, I was blind to the dictionary assignment.

Comment: Two improvements: (1) `mydict[1,2]` is equivalent to `mydict[(1,2)]` and looks a bit nicer.  (2) the `index` function call could easily be more expensive than constructing tuples, so you might want to inline the arithmetic.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge: 1: Valid point, though I'm trying to work out whether it is more instructive to make it an implicit tuple than an explicit one - I suspect with explicit it is easier to see that you could have `tup=(1,2); mydict[tup]`, though perhaps I should point that out. 2: I generally prefer indexing functions to be defined explicitly if the index is to be reused outside the current scope to avoid easily made but frustrating bugs. It is still an important point, though, so I will update.

Comment: No argument about the function being more reliable and debuggable.  But if you're doing an optimisation like this, it helps if the optimisation is actually faster :)

Comment: @PhilH: no I'm not doing parseAll things or similar. I'm writing a Graph class where edge have attributes, so when I specify the source and target nodes, the attributes are put inside the dictionary.
g.addEdge(1,2,"this edge attribute")

is implemented as
def addEdge(self,src,targ,attrib):
    edges[ src, targ ] = attrib

I also have to identify edges attributes from their source and target nodes, 
so I was wondering what is the fastest way to do this