# Dictionary of pair in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and was trying to make a `dict of pairs` in python.
What I would have done in `c++` is

```
dist[make_pair(a,b)]=1
```

I am not sure how I can do the same in python

**Edit**
What I basically want to do is to map a pair of two integers to some value-
for example-

```
(1,2) -> 1
(1,3) -> 2
(2,1) ->3
```

I want to map pairs to some integer value

Comment: I'm not sure either but only because I don't know what `make_pair` does or returns :)

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. It constructs a pair object with its first element set to a and its second element set to b.

Comment: What's the expected output? You should add a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question, if you want to get a proper answer?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375301/dictionary-where-keys-are-pair-of-integers-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the data structure "tuple" as a key in the dictionary. If you want to define a function that returns a n-tuple given n inputs, you can do that also.

```
a = 4
b = 5

dict_example = dict()
dict_example[(a,b)] = 1

print dict_example[(a,b)]
```

This prints the value of key (a,b), which is 1

Comment: Any immutable type will have a hash value which is the requirement of a dictionary key.

Comment: Note that it's the comma which make an expression create a tuple, not the parentheses, so you can omit those parentheses: `dict_example[a,b] = 1` will work just fine.

Comment: @Noober Both of these comments are great and improve my answer

Answer (score 2):

To create an element having the tuple (a,b) as key, and 1 as a value, you just have to do :

```
new_dict = {(a,b) : 1}
```

If such a dict already exist, and you want to add the pair a,b as a key and 1 as a value, you have to do :

```
existing_dict[(a,b)] = 1
```

You can also use `existing_dict[a,b] = 1` as Duncan pointed out.

Comment: Or just `existing_dict[a,b] = 1` for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you tried using an array as a dict key, like:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> pair = [0, 1]
>>> d[pair] = 'foo'
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Ok, what is that? Python dict keys must not be mutable. They can be numbers, strings and other hashable types - you can't use mutable types like lists, dicts and other mutable collections.

There is a collection that is very like a list but is not mutable: the tuple.

```
>>> d[tuple(pair)] = 'foo'
>>> d
{(1, 2): 'foo'}
```

As you can see, the literal for a tuple is `(v1, v2, ..., vN)`. In places where it is not ambiguous, you can even omit the parenthesis:

```
>>> pair = 0, 1
>>> pair
(0, 1)
```

More than once I was bit by this when I left a trailing comma while refactoring code:

```
>>> x = 1,   # I meant x = 1
>>> x
(1,)
```

That is the literal for a tuple with just 1 element.